# VBA Run time error '1004' ~ Sum if Function with variable sheet name in function

Tags: excel, vba

When coding a specific range of cells (column) with a sumif function within VBA i get an object or application defined error. The sumif function refers to another sheet,which is the same for all 4 variable sheets, in the workbook and is returned to 4 different sheets

The source sheet is the Machines sheet as shown in the code.

Is there someone who can help me with this error?

When I write the code without the variable sheetnames i do not get an error, I think my syntax is in the right order and the variable does return a value (L2 for the first i)

The code looks as follows:

```
Sub machine_stops_invoeren()
    Dim naam4 As String

    For i = 1 To 4        
        naam4 = Sheets("Settings").Range("B2").Offset(i, 0).Value        
        Sheets(naam4).Select
        Range("AH1").Formula = naam4        
        Range("AG2").FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=SUMIFS(Machines!C[-13],Machines!C[-15],"">""&'" & naam4 & "' !RC[-8],Machines!C[-14],""<""& '" & naam4 & "'!RC[-7], Machines!C[-27], ""<>OK"", Machines!C[-23], '" & naam4 & "' !R1C34)*86400"

        Range("AG2", "AG" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
        Range("AG1").Formula = "losse mach stops gedurende run"
    Next i
End Sub
```

I should get the return of a x amount of seconds during a specific time period on a specific production line (L2. L3, L5 or L6)( Hence the greater than and lesser than operators)

Comment: Just check what your variables return. Go through that code step by step using F8 and check which value `naam4` has in the case of error. You might benefit from reading [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) and [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: The return is correct, they generate the name of the first sheet. after that i get the 1004 error. Thanks for the reply anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't get the point of that code, because you loop from 1 to 4 but you write the formula always in the same place. So formula the previously written formula gets overwritten by the next and olny the very last loop will remain in the sheet.

This does not make any sense at all.

---

The actual issue is that you have errors in your formula.

#### How can you debug it?

Print your formula to the immediate window so you can check it.

```
Debug.Print "=SUMIFS(Machines!C[-13],Machines!C[-15],"">""&'" & naam4 & "' !RC[-8],Machines!C[-14],""<""& '" & naam4 & "'!RC[-7], Machines!C[-27], ""<>OK"", Machines!C[-23], '" & naam4 & "' !R1C34)*86400"
```

For example if `naam4` is `L1` the result will be the following:

```
=SUMIFS(Machines!C[-13],Machines!C[-15],">"&'L1' !RC[-8],Machines!C[-14],"<"& 'L1'!RC[-7], Machines!C[-27], "<>OK", Machines!C[-23], 'L1' !R1C34)*86400
```

and you will see that there are 2 additional spaces that are not allowed in these places. I marked them below:

```
=SUMIFS(Machines!C[-13],Machines!C[-15],">"&'L1' !RC[-8],Machines!C[-14],"<"& 'L1'!RC[-7], Machines!C[-27], "<>OK", Machines!C[-23], 'L1' !R1C34)*86400
'                                               ^                                                                                        ^
'                                               |                                                                                        |
'                                               | remove this space                                                                      | remove this space
```

Remove these spaces from your VBA code.